# PC under 2019 domain controller change the time by svchost

Tags: windows-10, date-time, windows-server-2019

I have a domain controller Windows 2019.

This domain is in Egypt, and as you know, the daylight feature has been activated this year.

I updated the domain so that the time zone can be changed without changing the region to Riyadh or Kuwait.

There are several Windows 10 devices under this domain, but without the update that is responsible for updating Time Zone because those PC is old.

This update depends on other updates that will make the pcs too slow, so we create a policy group was created to clone the registry files that are responsible for updating Egypt Time Zone and Dynamic DST from the domain to Clint PCs for a week till all PCs are updated by GP, It is confirmed that the recording files in the domain related to Time Zone Egypt and Dynamic DST have been copied and updated on the devices within that domain.

But occasionally some PCs return to their old status and cancel the daylight option and switch it to OFF!

After returning to `Regedit` and following the paths of the change, I found that a change had been made in:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Egypt Standard Time\Dynamic DST\2023 with different value from domain
```

The value of 2023 must be: (check the first image to see the difference)

```
"2023"=hex:88,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,0a,00,04,00,05,00,17,00,\
3b,00,3b,00,e7,03,00,00,04,00,04,00,05,00,17,00,3b,00,3b,00,e7,03
```

Also, after checking the event viewer and we found this msg:

> The system time has changed to ‎2023‎-‎07‎-‎18T11:35:49.353327200Z
> from ‎2023‎-‎07‎-‎18T11:35:49.352900300Z.

Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.

Process: '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\svchost.exe' (PID 1684).

I want to know what makes the PCs change and turned the daylight off.

Different between 2023 in registry image:

[image: different between 2023 in registry image]

Event viewer image:

[image: event viewer image]

Comment: More than just the registry key is required to support the time zone update. Without the corresponding Windows Update I don’t see a path forward